# How to leave elevated privileges and return back to normal

Tags: windows, visual-c++, nsis, uac

I have some old programs in C++ for Windows and I create installers for them with NSIS (Nullsoft Scriptable Install System). All these applications work in all systems from Windows 95 to Windows 10, but I have one strange issue related to UAC and installation.

When my "setup.exe" is started, it asks for elevated privileges so it can copy files to Program Files folder. That's good. But at the end of installation, it asks if I want to run the newly installed program. If I choose yes, the program is started **keeping the elevated privileges**. It means it has write access everywhere etc. That's not good. So I want to let the process switch itself back from admin to normal privileges with safe restricted access. How can I do this programmatically from my application? Is it even possible, when trying to keep compatibility with older Windows without UAC? Or is it possible only during startup of the process? (Maybe this is a flaw in NSIS installer or maybe I have a wrong install script, but if I was able to revoke admin rights at startup of my application, it would be the safest. There's no reason why to run as admin.)

I tried to google this, but although the internet is full of questions about UAC, it seems that all people want the very opposite thing to me. They want to have admin rights, I want to have a normal process.

Comment: Maybe this will help:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/enabling-and-disabling-privileges-in-c--

Comment: As an aside, [Inno Setup](https://jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) has a `[Run]` section (that can be used to launch a program at the end of the installation) defaults to `runasoriginaluser` (which is the default when using `postinstall`). If your installer is simple, it might be easier to use Inno Setup rather than NSIS.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a flaw in the UAC design, there is no easy way to go "back down" to a un-elevated process.

You technically have the same issue on 2000/XP if somebody right-clicks and uses "Run As" but that is rare on those systems.

My recommendation is to just remove the Run checkbox from the Finish page and let the user start your program from the Start Menu.

Your other alternatives are to define `MUI_FINISHPAGE_RUN_FUNCTION` and use [ShellExecAsUser](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/ShellExecAsUser_plug-in), [StdUtils.ExecShellAsUser](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/StdUtils_plug-in)  or the ugly Explorer hack (`Exec '"$WinDir\Explorer.exe" "$InstDir\MyApp.exe"'`).

The Explorer hack should not be used on XP/2003 or earlier (Use WinVer.nsh). On 98..XP/2003 it will display a security warning before running the file and on 95RTM/NT4 it will display a error message (will probably behave like 98 if IE4 is installed). I don't know what those other plug-ins do on XP/2003 or earlier.

The final option is the [UAC plug-in](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/UAC_plug-in). It is a bit complicated to use and abandoned by its author (me).